# SoapClient Formatted with "Soap-env" but the request don't need this

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I need send request for authenticate a SOAP via PHP SoapClient, but the request mount is result on "Not Found" after send.

On resume, using postman (plugin for chrome) i receive sucessful and the format XML mounted on a service is one and on another service is other. (each service mounted the XML different)

**Via Postman i send this format (XML):**
*Work Correctly: I receive the correct response from server.*

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AutenticarUsuario xmlns="http://tempuri.org/PortalUAU_WS/Autenticador">
      <Login>example</Login>
      <Senha>123456</Senha>
    </AutenticarUsuario>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Via SoapClient(PHP) he mount this format (XML):**
*Don't Work: I Receive "Not Found" no errors, no exceptions only "Not Found".*

CODE PHP

```
public function authUauWeb(){
        $soap = new \SoapClient($this->_wsEndpoint . 'Autenticador.asmx?WSDL', ['trace' => 1]);
        $result = $soap->AutenticarUsuario(['Login' => $this->_wsData->user, 'Senha' => $this->_wsData->pass]);



        //GET COOKIE SESSION
        $headers = $soap->__getLastResponseHeaders();
        $headers_init = strpos($headers, 'PortalUAU=');
        if($headers_init !== false){
            $headers = substr($headers, $headers_init);
            $headers_end = strpos($headers, ';');
            $headers = substr($headers, 0, $headers_end);
            $headers = explode('=', $headers);
        }

        if(isset($result->AutenticarUsuarioResult) && $result->AutenticarUsuarioResult == 'True' && gettype($headers) == 'array'){
            $this->_wsConnected = $headers;
        }else{
            $this->_wsConnected = false;
        }

        return $this->_wsConnected;
    }
```

XML STRUCTURE FROM PHP

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/PortalUAU_WS/Autenticador" xmlns:ns2="http://200.178.248.110:90/PortalUAU_WS_HLG/Autenticador.asmx" xmlns:ns3="text/xml; charset=utf-8">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:SOAPAction/>
        <ns3:ContentType/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:AutenticarUsuario>
            <ns1:Login>example</ns1:Login>
            <ns1:Senha>123456</ns1:Senha>
        </ns1:AutenticarUsuario>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As we say here on Brazil "My kick" is about this **soap** vs **SOAP-ENV** and **ns1:** present on tags from xml.

Thanks!

Comment: You need also show the PHP code how you create that (not working) request. What you guess the issue is (`SOAP-ENV` instead of `soap`) is not the issue, that is the namespace prefix and it is a valid one. It can be named differently, only needs to point to the same URI which is the case in your example. I would suspect more the Soap headers.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance @hakre, i included the php code